# ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, travis-ci

I have a problem with a test on travis-ci. I want to test color change of message and receive an error like in the title. Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

**Javascript**

```
test('red color', function(done) 
{
      var e = document.getElementById('messages');
      e.style.color = "#f00";
      done();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="messages"> 
<section id="messages"> 
<h2>Messages:</h2> 
{{#each messages}} 
<strong>{{name}}:</strong> {{message}}<br> 
{{/each}} 
</section> 
</template>
```

Comment: If that JavaScript code is executed on the server, the variable `document` wont be defined, cause it only exists on the client. Is it on the server you get the error?

Comment: @PeppeL-G I guess that the error comes from the server side, because html file is in `client` folder, and javascript file is placed inside `tests` folder. Also i found that it should looks like this `test('red color', function(done, client)` to run from client side but still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad not the same error but different - `Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

'Document' Is not defined in Meteor. You can try including JQuery to your code.
Something like: `$("#messages").css("color", "red");` will do the job. Here is some documentation: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

If you dont want to change your code use:
`var e = $("#messages");`